# How to search records from MongoDb based on a date fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Collection looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f2004484f78c4701b87117e"),
    "endTime" : 1595933768461.0,
    "startTime" : {
        "epoch" : 1595933767925.0
    },
    "error" : null,    
    "__v" : 0
}
```

From my UI I am doing a search to fetch records based on either of date field "endTime" or "startTime". The input from UI is 08/20/2020

The mongoose schema is defined like this

```
 new mongoose.Schema({
       endTime: { type: Number },
      startTime: { type: Object }
    });
```

I had been trying to identify different possibilities to fetch the records, but its not working..Can any one please help
Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.now(UI input)` and [lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) & [gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html) for finding data.
But it would be better if you could make the dates readable and then use with them aggregation operators, for example like this:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  endTime: { type: Date },
  startTime: { type: Date },
});
```

Or like this:

```
const { format } = require('date-fns');

new mongoose.Schema({
  endTime: {
    type: String,
    default: format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'), // or use format when u insert into DB
  },
  startTime: {
    type: String,
    default: format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'),
  },
});
```